# The Restful Services using ajax post method is working but when i call from angular its not woking

Tags: java, angularjs-directive, restful-architecture

i created the rest services in java.The Code

```
  @Path("/CommonDemo/{user}")
  public class CommonDemo  
  {

  @POST
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String result(@PathParam("user") String user)throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
     return user;
  } 
  }
```

i created the client in html file using ajax and this will work fine.

```
     function post1() 
    {
   var user="hi how are u";
   var url = "http://localhost:8080/Snefocare/CommonDemo/" +user;
       var xmlhttp = null;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  
             xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
               }  
         else if (window.ActiveXObject) {  
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
          }  
          else {  
              alert('Whoops! Your browser does not support XMLHttpRequest!');  
          }  
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {  
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {  
                  alert("Success");
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

           }  

     };  
       xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);  
       xmlhttp.send(null);  

   }
```

This above code is working and returning the result correct but same as i need to create client in angular so created the following way but its not working.These code.

```
    function post2()
   {

var user='hi how are u';

$http({method:'POST', url:'/CommonDemo', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},data:$.param(user)}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("success");
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("error");

  });

    }
```

also i included the angular file but its not affected anything.

Comment: have u verified what request URL and params are going when u use angularjs?

Comment: actually i am new in angular so i do not know how to check.